# Springfox Java Bean Validations not displaying Validation Groups in Swagger Output

Tags: openapi, springfox

I have a spring boot app that I have implemented JSR validation groups in.

```
@Size(max=100, groups = {SomeGroup.class})
@Size(max=50, groups = {SomeOtherGroup1.class,SomeOtherGroup2.class})
private String someString;
```

I am trying to get these groups reflected in my API documentation, but with no luck.  I am currently using springfox 3.0.  Is there a way to accomplish this with springfox?  If not are there other documentation frameworks that can handle displaying what groups a field is required for?

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a ModelPropertyBuilderPlugin similar to what is here: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2739

My swagger page now shows something similar to:

```
example: someString
x-1-validation-type-Size: groups: SomeGroup | other attributes: min: 0, max: 100
x-2-validation-type-Size: groups: SomeOtherGroup1, SomeOtherGroup2 | other attributes: min: 0, max: 50

description of someString
```

creating a list of `springfox.documentation.service.VendorExtension` and then setting it like below.

```
context.getSpecificationBuilder().vendorExtensions(extensions);
context.getBuilder().extensions(extensions);
```